# Rails how to link to the author of a post or a review?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, author

```
 link_to review.author_id, profile_path(review.author_id)
```

Returns No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

It's because review.author_id displays the author_id correctly. But it does work when passed as a parameter to profile_path.

Changing it to #review.author_id does not fix the error

In another module of my site works perfectly

```
link_to "View Profile", profile_path(@story.user_id)
```

I think it maybe because user is a class, while author is not, can I pass the author_id as an integer or index into profile_path directly?

Comment: No - its because you have not assigned a user to `review.author`- its nil. You're most likely missing a validation that ensures that a review cannot be created without an author.

Comment: but review.author_id returns the id of the author, regardless if review.author is nil, there is no way to just pass the value of review.author_id as an integer?

Comment: You're basically just sprouting out a bunch of nonsense about how you think it works. How are we actually supposed to help you?

Comment: Since I recognize this code from your previous question then `author` is just an "aliased association" its just an association where the name of the association is not the same as the class. It works exactly like any other association. And yes it has a class.

Comment: `review.author_id` would give the id as a integer- if there was one. the real  issue you should be looking at is why review.author_id is nil.

Comment: the issue is that review.author_id is not nil, it gives the author_id of the author. Anyway I fixed it, I added a review.author_id .to_i, it converts it to a integer value then passes into the profile(id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I solved it

```
link_to review.author_id, profile_path(review.author_id.to_i) %>
```

EDIT:

Apparently review.author_id causes profile_path to interpret it as an object, while a to_s tells it to take review.author_id as a value.

Which profile_path can also take as a parameter

Comment: You're just doing something very wrong - the path helpers do take strings. Try `profile_path("foo")`. Or `profile_path(review.author)`.

Comment: I just tried it, it links to an nonexistent user. I found it odd that to_i was required for it to work. But yes profile_path does take a string as a parameter

Comment: Maybe it's because it was trying to pass review.author_id as a class and didn't know I wanted passed as a integer. A to_s allows it to pass as it's value rather than an object/class. While "foo" works because it's being passed as a value rather than an object

Comment: So what you're doing by putting to_i on it is just coercing the value. `nil.to__i = 0`. So you really just masked the bug in your application.

Comment: No its not. Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and starting looking for why its nil instead. Or maybe your trying to link to a record that has not been saved at all.

Comment: it's nil because author is not a class it recognised, so when I pass review.author_id it tries to take the object (which it can't find). When a to_i is used it takes it as a value instead which it does detect, but you make a good point, I'll take a look at the author class and see any bugs, thanks for your help!

Comment: None of this stuff you are sprouting is even remotely close to the truth. review.author_id should be an integer. An integer is an object, as is a string - in Ruby everything is an object. `review.author` would give you a User record.